# Generating Secure Keys for Solr Communication in alfersco 5.1

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We have [installed](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/solr4-install-config.html) Alfersco 5.1 and Solr in different servers .
Alfresco has been started but I couldn't find the keystore  folder in:

```
 <ALFRESCO_TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/keystore .
```

Its little bit confusion in the documentation between implementing 7th point and solr secure communication link. I want to go for solr secure communication,so we have followed the below link.

Generating Secure Keys for Solr Communication

I have implemented generating secure keys by executing `generatekeystore.bat` file and I kept the newly generated truststore and keystore files in:

```
<ALFRESCO_HOME>/alf_data/keystore
```

path and point the paths in tomcat `server.xml` for both tomcat alfresco and solr servers.

**When should we go for 7th point?**

Please find the text of mentioned 7<sup>th</sup> bullet below.

7.Create and populate a keystore directory for the Alfresco and Solr servers. By default, the keystore directory is created in `/alf_data/keystore`. Note that at this stage the keystore directory will just be a template, containing standard keys. To secure the installation, you must follow the steps to generate new keys as explained in the Generating Secure Keys for Solr Communication section. For example:

For Unix:

```
mkdir -p <ALFRESCO_HOME>/alf_data/keystore  cp <ALFRESCO_TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/keystore/* <ALFRESCO_HOME>/alf_data/keystore
```

For Windows:

```
mkdir <ALFRESCO_HOME>\alf_data\keystore  copy <ALFRESCO_TOMCAT_HOME>\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\keystore\* <ALFRESCO_HOME>\alf_data\keystore
```

Comment: Can you include a reference to where you got this documentation. It seems like it might be a bug or you might be reading a version of the doc that doesn't align with the version you are installing. Also, if you use the installer, you'll save yourself this trouble.

Comment: see 7th point in below link.http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/solr4-install-config.html;as you said we have used zip.Is there any separate zip file to install for solr4 for alfresco5.1 version.

Comment: if its not there ,do we need to create keystore folder & add keystore files in this path;<ALFRESCO_TOMCAT_HOME>\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\keystore

Comment: I don't know why you would have a keystore directory in that path. I'm looking at my local installs and they all have keystore directories under alf_data, the content store. That directory can live anywhere. The thing that tells Alfresco where it is is the alfresco-global.properties file (dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore).